# How SHOULD I inject document and window instances in angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular

I want to make testeable component but I need to use the window or document instance.

Does angular 2 provides a way to inject this kind of html specific objects in order to allow the mocking during testing?

Comment: Do you want something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042941/how-to-mock-angularfire-2-service-in-unit-test/38043920#38043920 ?

Comment: The pointed question resolves how to inject document but I want to get window too. I can't find a window provider in browser_adapter